# pass multidimensional array in collection view inside the table view

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, multidimensional-array

Please find the photo i want this type of view tableview with collection view  [image]
here members array is every time different means members are not fix in every cell,    please help me out, ... thanks

Comment: Can you add the code where you configure the cell? That will help a lot. It sounds like a cell reuse issue.

Comment: just tell me how to add value in array

Answer (score 0):

Although it is based on how your application getting the data, for such a case, -in general- I would suggest to create your own *custom* Model instead of just declaring arrays/dictionaries of arrays. Example:

```
struct Family {
    var title: String
    var thumbnail: UIImage
    var members: [Member]
}

struct Member {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var thumbnail: UIImage
}
```

so forth You could declare such an array of families:

```
let families = [Family(title: "YOGA", thumbnail: UIImage(named: "YOGA.jpg"), members: [Member(firstName: "John", lastName: "Smith", thumbnail: UIImage(named: "John.jpg"))]),
                Family(title: "DEMO1", thumbnail: UIImage(named: "DEMO_1.jpg"), members: [Member(firstName: "Foo", lastName: "Bar", thumbnail: UIImage(named: "Foo.jpg"))])]
// and so on...
```

thus the data source for the table view would be the `families`, each collection view in the table view cell data source would be the `members` of the current family.

By following this approach you could easily *templating* your data to be more expressive.